# Parse sql script before execution using c#

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a rich text field in my winform app where I can write sql script
and need to check whether any issue is there in written script or not.
Is there any way to do the same task just before it's execution using c#?
Any type of suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: can u elaborate ur question? what do u mean by parse sql script?

Comment: @Newton Sheikh, I have updated my requirement.Would you like to check again?

Comment: @Anil I still don't think it's enough. What do you want to check for?

Comment: You want to check whether your script is right or wrong before execution.  Right?

Comment: i get ur question. U want to check if the sql query is valid or not before actually firing it on sql server or oracle or whatever. Well its quite tough. All u can do is check if the query syntax is valid or not(still its loads of coding). Try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1294/SQL-Syntax-Validator

Comment: @user1671639 Yes, I want to check whether my written script is valid or not before it's actual exicution.If you have any thought then you can share with me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only trying to validate the syntax (and not the existence of the database objects), you may take a look at the [TSqlParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsqlparser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You will need to add the following references to your project:

- *Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom*
- *Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql*

A simple way to do that is to edit your *.csproj* file and add the following two entries along with the existing ones and reload the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql" />
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom" />
  <!-- other Reference tags -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Some sample usage:

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parser = new TSql100Parser(true);
    IList<ParseError> errors;
    var result = parser.Parse(new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text), out errors);
    // TODO: check the errors
}
```